# Reactjs and firebase ::net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-redux

This is a react project and I got the following error, I make a separate folder for Axios the code of that file is given below and after that I import it,

```
import axios from 'axios';

const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://burger-builder-urro.firebaseio.com/'
});

export default instance;
```

And the code of another file from where I want to post data is given bellow:

```
    purchasecontinuedHandler= ()=>{
            // alert("You Continue");
    
            const order = {
                ingredients: this.state.ingredients,
                price: this.state.totalprice,
                customer : {
                    name: "Mubarra",
                    address: {
                        street: 'Teststreet 1',
                        zipcode: '9382',
                        country: 'pakistan'
                    },
                    email: 'mubarraajmal.uet@gmail.com'
                },
                deliveryMethod : 'fastest'
            }
            axios.post('/orders.json', order)
                .then(response => console.log(response))
                .catch(error => console.log(error));
        }
```

I really do not know Why it's showing this error:

[image: this is the following error which I got]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you attaching the baseURL with axios Post? I think you forgot to append that?

Comment: what do you mean from append?

Comment: You have exported instance, but where did you used while posting? You have used axios.post again? not the instance.post?

Comment: But I import it like this:: import axios from '../../axios-order'; then therefore i used axios.post!!

Comment: oh, it works now, Thanks a lot sir. sir import name should be the same as the component name??

Comment: When you do a default export name can be any, but in case if you need to export more than one function or class, the name should be same!. For such export you need to import like import { name } from 'location'

Comment: sir can you answer this question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67195846/retrieve-data-from-multiple-documents-from-firestore. I will be really thankfull sir