# Retrieve data from multiple documents from Firestore

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, foreach, data-retrieval

I tried a lot of times but I am still not able to retrieve data from multiple documents, The below screenshot shows that I have 3 documents in my collection and my question is how to retrieve data from each of them.

[image]

[image]

I used foreach loop to loop through all the documents but I don't know how to retrieve data from id **RoKQBRcuaVfcGPKNswbx** or id **Y8KbSQHcuxctJCJ1lWYH** because it auto retrieve the data of the last id.

I really need your help, please.
Thank you.

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and [edit] your question to include code **and** data as text, not images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `snapshot` object contains all the 3 documents in your collection. You must iterate over all and render data to your HTML as explained below.

```
db.collection("Policies List").get().then((snapshot) => {
  const documents = snapshot.docs //array of documents
  documents.forEach((doc) => {
    const docData = doc.data() //Data of that single document
    console.log(docData)
    renderToHtml() // Code that creates new HTML elements
  })
})
```

This way you are creating new HTML elements for all the documents in your collection. The `renderToHtml()` function will contain that `.innerHTML` code.
Please make sure to see the logs in the console. They'll help understand the structure in a better way.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply, sir I can not understand any other way of rendering like you said to use renderToHtml(), I used the way as I shared in the above screenshot.  sir can you help me to elaborate a little bit. Thanks

Comment: mean how do I access other documents like having id (RoKQBRcuaVfcGPKNswbx) or id (Y8KbSQHcuxctJCJ1lWYH), it just auto retrieves the data of the last id (yHfK2wE6ZYRIL1dpoFRp).

Comment: @saqibdiar do you want to get data of the specific document? Then you can do this: `db.collection("Policies List").document("yHfK2wE6ZYRIL1dpoFRp").get()`

Comment: yes I also want that but it's not working sir

Comment: @saqibdiar please share a screenshot of the errors

Comment: There isn't an option to send you a screenshot !!!!

Comment: secpolicyfetching.js:33 Uncaught TypeError: db.collection(...).document is not a function
    at secpolicyfetching.js:33......... this is the error

Comment: db.collection("Policies List").document("yHfK2wE6ZYRIL1dpoFRp").get().then((snapshot)=>{
      console.log(snapshot.doc);
})  when i did this i got the above error

Comment: @saqibdiar if you request a single document by specific doc ID, then you get the document snapshot it self. So please try `snapshot.data()` there.

Comment: There's one more correction, it's `.doc()` and not `.document()`

Comment: yes sir it worked now, thanks a lot. sir but retrieving multiple documents is still the problem because I do not know how to deal with it, in simple words, I want to retrieve some of the data from all that (3) documents in a single page, which mean those three docs are the requests I want to show those requests in single-page e.g: title and company name of the first doc and similarly for the rest two docs to.

Comment: @saqibdiar great now that you know how to fetch a single document, lets try fetching multiple documents. To fetch all the documents in the collection you just need to make this query, `db.collection("Policies List").get()` this will return an array of all the documents in that collection. To view the data please try this code: `snapshot.docs`. Please let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Yes sir, it also worked but the problem is that it is a foreach loop so it will return the data of all three documents on one page because its loop, but I want to loop these all and retrieve them on different pages like document one from the collection have there own page and document two have their own page and so on.